# Is it possible to run a private mailserver?

Tags: email, domain, exim

Last week my email provider (mout.web.de) got listed on spamcop. So I cannot send emails to recipients whose mailserver uses spamcop. An obvious solotion, which popped up in the forums, is to switch to another (paid) email provider.

Since I have a local mailserver (exim) running anyways, I wonder whether I can set it up in way so it delivers mail directly rather than sending it to a smarthost, as it does now. If spamcop then detects spam originating from my IP, I am willing to take the blame.

However I do not own my own domain (just a dynamic dns listing) and I am worried that this could be a showstopper.

I also vaguely recall, that years ago a friend of mine tried to deliver mails directly and ran into problems, beause some mailservers would refuse to accept mail from him (the exact details slipped my memory).

So

- Is running my own mailserver (without smarthost) a vital alternative to switching to a different email provider?
- Will I have to register my own domain?
- Are there any other showstoppers? Is there anything an email provider can do, which I cannot do on my linux box?

Comment: You may find this thread to be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/2630399/18309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In general this is possible, that's what email providers do.
2. You surely need your own domain.
3. Many ISPs have blocks in place so you're forced to go over your ISPs server.
4. Even if your ISP does not block port 25, mail from your IP range will very likely be marked as spam if you run it from a home connection.
5. Email is a complicated and critical piece of the infrastructure which takes some effort to secure. Furthermore, you will have to put additional effort into making it reliable (redundancy, failover, etc.)

#### Conclusion

Although it's possible to set it up on your own, renting a server in a data centre or paying an email provider if you want a reliable operating mail setup without a high risk of being marked as spammer is often the better solution.

Comment: I maintain my own Sendmail server and luckily my ISP allows it. I do run into problems with sending mail and have to maintain a mailertable in Sendmail which says which domains need to be forwarded through my ISP's mailserver rather than mine due to the IPs I generally have access to are often times on spamhaus etc.

Comment: @slm Exactly that's what I meant in point 4 (and point 3 for that matter, since you're forced to use your ISPs mail server). Depending on the reasons of running your own mail server (security, full control over data, experience, etc.) in general I advice against running mail servers from home connections.

Comment: Yup I was just giving an example of how one would do this via the mailertable facility in Sendmail.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is spam. There is no 'standard' method for preventing spam, everybody uses different methods, and few provide any information about how their spam detection works. Even if you set up your system securely and correctly, you may be blacklisted simply because your host is in a listed DHCP block. Really you need a static IP address *and* the ability to configure the PTR record as well as the A/AAA rrecords (and of course SPF in your TXT records).

Dynamic DNS is not a show stopper, but a changing IP address and no PTR record mean that you will run into problems very quickly.

Domainkeys/DMARC is a good idea too.

But even then there are pitfalls to managing an email server: send too many emails to hotmail/Yahoo/gmail too quickly and you'll get blacklisted - meaning yo need to ensure that you've got throttling in place. Running a trained baysian filter on outgoing email is a good idea too.

Usually it's a lot cheaper/more reliable to look for a specialist SMTP provider.